# Migrate Applications with ADFS Activity Report

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

We are using the ADFS activity report to migrate our applications to AAD.  Everything shows as Ready and when we click on the Ready link, the text says "We've detected on-premises settings for this relying party that can be migrated to a new Azure AD enterprise application.  We'll map the fields and create the new application, but users won't be redirected to it until you say so."  By the last statement, it seems like the application is automatically created now.  Is that the case?  If so, how long does it take to create the application and does it keep the same name as in ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   The message that you encountered “We've detected on-premises settings for this relying party that can be migrated to a new Azure AD enterprise application. We'll map the fields and create the new application, but users won't be redirected to it until you say so.” Means that the application is a SaaS application available in Enterprise application gallery in Azure AD. This does not in anyway mean that the application has been created automatically, it just means that the application is ready to be migrated to Azure AD and is fully available as a SaaS application in Azure AD gallery and doesn’t need any further relying party configuration migration from the on-premises ADFS server.

•   Since the message is displayed only for SaaS apps readily available in Azure AD gallery and are equally configured as a relying party trust in ADFS, its configuration information is readily migrated through the ADFS Connect health application to Azure AD and it can be configured in the cloud itself with admin account access needed for the SaaS application’s account for SSO and SAML authentication configuration required through Azure AD.

You can find the image below for your reference, it shows the ‘Dropbox’ application as ready for migration from ADFS to Azure AD: -

[image: ADFS application health report]
[image: Application migration information]
[image: Azure AD application configuration]

Through the above option enabled, you can easily configure your application’s SSO configuration in Azure AD. If all the configurations are up and running, it will happen instantaneously within a few minutes of time.

Kindly refer to this link for more information on migrating federated apps from ADFS to Azure AD: -

https://github.com/AzureAD/Deployment-Plans/tree/master/ADFS%20to%20AzureAD%20App%20Migration

Answer (score 0):

I think the report is still in preview and it is missing a create application button.
All the documentation only shows the reports & not the create process.

Also this migration tool, is a repackage of the powershell test commands:
https://github.com/AzureAD/Deployment-Plans/tree/master/ADFS%20to%20AzureAD%20App%20Migration

So I assume you need to create the application manually based on the report.